# Out of bounds error using ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have been trying to convert a JavaScript function to a Java method, whereby a number is passed by argument and if two concurrent numbers are even a dash "-" would be placed between them.

This works fine as long as the last digit is not even, if it is even I get an out of bounds error which I'm assuming is to do with the if statement using `arr2.get(i + 1)` where the first part of the condition is `true` but the second can not be met due to reaching the end of the list. Is there an easy way to correct the logic here?

I am fairly new to Java and struggling with some problems I can solve easily in JavaScript due to how some of the data stuctures act differently.

```
public void dash(int someNumber) {
    int num = someNumber;
    String str = String.valueOf(num);
    String arr1[] = str.split("");
    String result = "";
    ArrayList<Integer> arr2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        int temp = Integer.parseInt(arr1[i]);
        arr2.add(temp); 
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < arr2.size(); i++) {

         if (arr2.get(i) % 2 == 0 && arr2.get(i + 1) % 2 == 0) {

            result = result + arr2.get(i) + "-";

        }

        else{
            result = result + arr2.get(i);
        }


    }
    System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

And the `main`.

```
public class mainController {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DashSort ds = new DashSort();
        ds.dash(245461);

    }

}
```

Changed if statment to this and seems to work fine.

```
    if (i + 1 == arr2.size()) {

result = result + arr2.get(i);  
}
else if (arr2.get(i) % 2 == 0 && i < arr2.size() && arr2.get(i + 1) % 2 ==0) {


        result = result + arr2.get(i) + "-";
    }

    else{
        result = result + arr2.get(i);
    }
```

Comment: so, you try to get an element that doesn't exist. does it surprise you that leads to issue? if i is the biggest possible index, don't try to get element (i+1)

Comment: do you tried to trace you code step-by-step? (with Eclipse\Idea debugger)

Answer (score 4):

Either change it to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr2.size()-1; i++) {
```

Or don't check `i+1` if `i ==arr2.size()`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to `String.valueOf(num)`, `str.split("")` or `Integer.parseInt(arr1[i])` if you only use strings for the output and work decimal digit-by-digit using integers:

```
public static void dash(int someNumber) {
    int lastDigit = 1;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while (someNumber > 0)
    {
        int currentDigit = someNumber % 10;
        someNumber /= 10;
        if (lastDigit % 2==0 && currentDigit % 2==0)
          sb.append('-');
        sb.append(currentDigit);
        lastDigit = currentDigit;
    }

    String result = sb.reverse().toString(); //reverse because we processed the digits in reverse order

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: @Dcoto Was this any help to you? Please upvote or accept helpful suggestions.